# How to get a particular Value form ModelAndView object within a function after setting the value

Tags: spring-mvc

How to get a particular value from ModelAndView object?

for eg:i set the value using   `modelmap.put(WebKeys.BYTE_ARRAY, byteArray);` and set otherfield value likewise then after added all value using   `modelView.addallobjects(modelmap)` .   I called a method `doaddlogo(ModelView modelview,DapAttachmentBean dapattachmentbean)` and within that method i want to access particular value like `WebKeys.BYTE_ARRAY.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `modelAndView.getModel().get(WebKeys.BYTE_ARRAY)` - http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/portlet/ModelAndView.html